# looking for SQL insert syntax for informix via python informixdb

Tags: python, sql, informix

Cant find the correct syntax for INSERT query with python informixdb

- python 2.6.6
- python INFORMIXDB version 2.5
- driver name : IBM Informix-ESQL
- driver version : 3.50.FC8
- on debian squeeze

here's the doc - http://informixdb.sourceforge.net/manual.html#binding-parameters

```
>>> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO names VALUES(:first,:last,:age)',
...                dict(first='some', last='body', age=56) )
```

So i tried for example

```
 cursor.execute('INSERT INTO transit_auftrag_i VALUES(:auftragskey,:transitkunde,:status)',dict(auftragskey='erII',transitkunde='DMIeLE',status='OK') )
```

this is what i get in this example

```
<class '_informixdb.ProgrammingError'>
('PREPARE', -236, [{'message': 'Insert value list does not match column list', 'sqlstate': '21S01'}])
<class '_informixdb.ProgrammingError'>
('DESCRIBE', -410, [{'message': 'Syntax error or access violation in PREPARE or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE', 'sqlstate': '37000'}])
Segmentation fault
```

any hints what i could try please?

UPDATE: informix 11.50.xC8

**UPDATE**

thanks so far. I do the following query now which runs without errors, but also with no message from the cursor and it does not insert anything. If you have a suggestion it would be great.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO transit_auftrag_i (auftragskey,transitkunde,status) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)", dict(a='A',b='B',c='C') )
```

Comment: seems i Got it. I needed to set conn.autocommit = True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should list the columns explicitely that you want to populate:

`INSERT INTO names (firstname, lastname, age) VALUES (:first,:last,:age)`

Apperently your table has more columns than you supply, or they are in a different order.

Not stating the columns for an `INSERT` statement is a bad programming habit, that you should get rid off as quick as possible

Comment: i assumed the part `(:auftragskey,:transitkunde,:status)` IS my column list!!? I' ll try

Comment: No, those are the values for the columns (That's why it's in the `VALUES` part) and the dict() part refers to the *parameter* names, not the *column* names

Answer (score 0):

If your database table has a lot of columns, consider also creating a class containing enumerated types, and refer to the columns by name. At the beginning of our AMR project 1 1/2 years ago, I tried referring to columns using just index numbers on a 20+ column table (data input from a vendor); it was a disaster, until I created a class.

The following is for Python 2.6.5.

```
premid = mapErtToPremId(ins_row[d.DeviceID], ins_row[d.DeviceType], ins_row[d.ChannelNumber], db)


class drIdx():
    def __init__(self):
        self.MeterID = 0
        self.Reading = 1
        self.ReadingDateTime = 2
        self.Account = 3
        self.CustomerLN = 4
        self.CustomerFN = 5
        self.DeviceID = 6
        self.DeviceType = 7
        self.ChannelNumber = 8
        self.DecodeType = 9
        self.LoadDateLocal = 10
        self.PremiseID = 11
```